# Magento - only show current category in url

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, seo, magento-1.7

I want to improve my URL SEO structure on my magento site.

I want to display just the current category appending on the url when in a category page.

For example currently the site outputs this when on 2nd-level-cat

### www.myexamplesite.com/1st-level-cat/2nd-level-cat

The desired out i wish to achieve is this, when on my 2nd-level-cat.

### www.myexamplesite.com/2nd-level-cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following extension does exactly what you want.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/category-url-seo-free.html

It will ignore parent level category in URL